Intersection of discriminated unions behaves strange
Here we have an example with discriminated unions:
type A = { a: true } | { a?: false }
type B = { b: true } | { b?: false }

type C = A & B

let c: C = {}

c = {
    a: true,
}

c = {
    b: false,
}

c = {
    a: true as boolean,
    b: false as boolean
}

c = { // ts err
    a: true as boolean,
}

c = { // ts err
    b: false as boolean,
}

How should I write a C type to make all of these examples valid?

I'd say you should try to merge/flatten A and B before intersecting them, possibly like this playground link shows. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Merge util is helpful, thanks for that! But I still can't understand the reason why ts acts so weird in such cases.
If we use only one union - its ok.
If we use unions without optional parameters - its ok.
But if we use multiple union, which contain optional props - it doesnt work.
Could you please explain why?

That's outside the scope of the current question. If you want that answered then you should open a new question for it. I suspect the details are either to be found in ms/TS#30779 and ms/TS#57013 or possibly we'd need to open a new github issue asking about it. Since you explicitly removed that part from this question in order to make it properly focused, I'm not inclined to spend a lot of time thinking about that here. So, shall I write an answer to this question (which will touch on but not necessarily definitively answer the other part of your question)?

Definitely do that since your example resolves the issue.

Generally speaking TypeScript does not consider an object type with a union of properties to be assignable to a union of object types:
const v: { x: string } | { x: number } =
    { x: Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : 1 }; // error

You might say "well, {a: string | number} is always either a {a: string} or a {a: number} so they should be equivalent." But such equivalences tend to be fragile (they break if you add random properties) and hard to discover without a lot of extra work (they scale badly with the size of the union) so TypeScript mostly just fails to verify them.
Before TypeScript 3.5 it always failed to see such equivalences. But TypeScript 3.5 introduced so-called smarter union checking, as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#30779. Now if you try to assign an object-of-unions to a union-of-objects it might succeed, if the type you're assigning to is a discriminated union and the object you're assigning from expands to fewer than 25 union members when it tries to analyze them, and... well, it's fragile and complicated, you can read about it in microsoft/TypeScript#30779 above. And there are known bugs or limitations in it, such as microsoft/TypeScript#57013 and microsoft/TypeScript#59716.
When in doubt, you should not rely on such equivalences in your code.

So instead of trying to assign {a?: boolean, b?: boolean} to A & B, which is {a: true, b: true} | {a: true, b?: false} | {a?: false, b: true} | {a?: false, b?: false}, I'd say you should just try to compute {a?: boolean} from A and {b?: boolean} from B before the intersection, which gives you {a?: boolean, b?: boolean}.
Maybe like this:
type Merge<T> = [T] extends infer U extends [any] ?
    { [K in keyof U[0]]: U[0][K] } : never

type C = Merge<A> & Merge<B>
/* type C = {
    a?: boolean | undefined;
} & {
    b?: boolean | undefined;
} */

The Merge<T> type mostly just performs an identify mapped type on the properties of T, but it keeps T as a single object type.  If you tried to refactor that to {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}, TypeScript would automatically distribute that across unions in T, because T is a bare generic type parameter. You explicitly don't want Merge<X | Y> to be evaluated as Merge<X> | Merge<Y>.
To avoid distribution over unions, we need to write the mapped type over something other than a bare generic type parameter. I've used infer to "copy" [T] into a new generic type parameter U, so U[0] is the original T. But since U[0] is not a bare type parameter, mapping over K in keyof U[0] doesn't trigger the distributive behavior.
Anyway, Merge<A> produces {a?: boolean} and Merge<B> produces {b?: boolean}, and the intersection works with all your examples:
let c: C;
c = {}; // okay
c = { a: true }; // okay
c = { b: false }; // okay
c = { a: Math.random() < 0.5, b: Math.random() < 0.5 }; // okay
c = { a: Math.random() < 0.5 }; // okay
c = { b: Math.random() < 0.5, }; // okay

Looks good!
Playground link to code
